# Ant exec as different user on Windows

Tags: windows, ant

I would like to run an executable as a different user in ant on **Windows**. I was thinking of invoking [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run on the same machine and passing in a username and password. Is there a better way to do this? The answers I have found so far are for running ant on Linux/Unix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) utility to run an executable as a different user.

> Allows a user to run specific tools and programs with different permissions than the user's current logon provides.

Answer (score 1):

In windows versions previous to Windows 7, you should be able to simply right click on the executable and select "Run As". You can then select the user from a drop down list of available users.. In Windows 7, this option has been replaced with the "Run as Administrator" option.

From the windows pages at Microsoft:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/What-happened-to-the-Run-as-command

If you are logged on as a standard user, you can also use the Run as administrator command to run a program as another user, even if the user does not have an administrator account. To do this, click Run as administrator, and then select the user account. If you are logged on as an administrator, you will need to type runas.exe /user name in the Command Prompt window if you want to run a program as another user.

Comment: +1 for mentioning runas but I'm doing this from inside an ant script.